# How to select multiple items to delete (via checkbox) in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a column of checkboxes where in users can select multiple items to delete on a table. Something like this but only a button "Bulk Delete":

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<%= render "shared/nav_dashboard" %>
<%= render "shared/header_dashboard" %>

  <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Page Header-->
          <header> 
            <h1 class="h3 display">Pages</h1>
          </header>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h4>List of Pages</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                         <th><%= link_to "Bulk Delete", page_path(page), method: :delete, data: {  confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></th>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Title</th>
                          <th>Summary</th>
                          <th>Date Created</th>
                          <th colspan="3">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <% @pages.each do |page| %>
                        <tr>
                          <td><input type="checkbox" value="false"> </td>
                          <td scope="row"><%= page.id %></td>
                          <td><%= page.title %></td>
                          <td><%= page.body.truncate(60) %></td>
                          <td> <%= page.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %> </td>
                        <td><%= link_to "Show", page_path(page)%></td>
                         <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_page_path(page)%></td>
                          <td><%= link_to "Delete", page_path(page), method: :delete, data: {  confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <% end %>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


      </section>


<%= render "shared/footer_dashboard" %>
```

I am wondering why it did not work?

How can I do this functionality step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You could to use a form. It'll look something like this (I'm using simpleform, but this will work for every your preferred form-tag helper):

In `routes.rb`:

```
resources :pages do 
  collection do 
    delete :bulk_destroy
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= simple_form_for :pages, url: "/pages/bulk_destroy", method: :delete do |f| %> 
  <ul>
    <% @pages.each do |page| %>
      <li> <%= page.name %> <input type="checkbox" name="collection_ids[]" value="<%= page.id %>" /> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def bulk_destroy
    Page.where(id: params[:collection_ids]).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Heavy-lifting taken care for you: https://github.com/joshmn/active_action or check out the bare-minimum proof of concept at https://github.com/joshmn/bulk_actions_poc

Comment: do i need to install the simple_form gem here?

Comment: you don't _need_ to, you can use the built-in form tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't prefer to write other separate method then you can try like below, you just need to be sure that when multiple ids are selected it should send as params[:ids] rather then params[:id]

```
def destroy
  ids = params[:ids].present? ? params[:ids] : [parmas[:id]]
  Pages.where(id: ids).destroy
end
```

Comment: would the views still the same?

Comment: can you provide extra codes on how it will look on views also like the bulk button above

Comment: there will be change on view side , like , you can do it two way 1). create form and add hidden field inside it with param named ids , 2). write a jquery which will fire on click of bulk delete , that way , writing jquery will even reduce the code i wrote.

Comment: if you want me to code then i can provide separate ans for this , i will write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to change syntax based on you jquery version

```
$('#bulk_delete').on('click', function(e){
  var selectedIds = [];
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(e){
    ids.push($(this).data('id'))
  })
  $.ajax({url: 'your action url',type: 'DELETE', data: {ids: selectedIds}})
})
```

Comment: Is there a vanilla javascript version of this?